# How to use a local node.js library in production?

Tags: javascript, node.js, production

I have a library in folder `common` with `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "common",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

I have another project that uses this library, in folder `article` with `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "article",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.1.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

Locally I did:

```
cd common
yarn link
cd ../article
yarn link common
```

This works fine I locally publish library and use it.

Now I want to deploy this project to CI, and I don't know how to make it work in another computer. Do I have to run this as a script, or is there a better way to use a local library.

Comment: I think the only way is to publish it as a package. Not 100% sure though

Comment: I am sure `common` name is taken and I don't want to change library name

Comment: Yeah, you'd have to choose a different name: https://www.npmjs.com/package/common

Comment: I've seen libraries using a dedicated `./lib/` folder for the additional `.js` files, not sure if it would work fine for you, tho.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to create a module, you would want to get the code out to someplace like a repository so other env can access it. Perhaps try using it from git hub using the method from this article:

https://medium.com/pravin-lolage/how-to-use-your-own-package-from-git-repository-as-a-node-module-8b543c13957e

Answer (score 1):

There is something called Yarn Workspaces: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/workspaces/.

Basically in the root of your project you create a `package.json` file and add these properties in:

```
{
  "workspaces": [
    "common",
    "article"
  ]
}
```

and run `yarn install` and now you can use these local libraries within your other projects.